# Set website background image for iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, image, background

Is there a specific way you have to set the background image for it to appear on IOS devices?

the image appears on my laptop but all I get is a white background on my iPad.

I've assigned the image with:

```
body {
background-image: url(background.jpg);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try adding repeat to it and see if it works e.g. body {
background-image: url(background.jpg) repeat;
}

Comment: hi Ben, I have the website password protected at the minute, and my hosts website seems to be down, I'll send the URL as soon as I can remove the password

Comment: @Satya, when I add repeat it takes away the background completely

Comment: need to see the demo url only then I can say anything further

Comment: try adding it to the html tag as well and or applying a width and height of 100% on both the html and the body tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {background-image: url("../background.jpg") no-repeat scroll center 100px;}
```

i use this to center on ipad, try this out

Comment: You probably mean `background` here, not `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys sorry for the delay in replying.

I just simply added the background-image into my body tag on the html and it loaded without a problem

thanks for the help

Comment: thats bad practice, try to use external css file, check my answer and try, if it dont work try getting the absolue path where the image is.

Comment: hi Ark, I tried your solution, it seems if I enter anything after the "..jpg)" the background image disappears altogether. my host is still having issues and I can't get in to my account to give access to the url

Comment: are you closing with quotes the image url?